# ARKit image recognition and text display

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, coreml

I need a project for an application on museums, to implement the functionality that when I frame the paintings of my choice, I visualize the text in AR if possible. Do you think it's feasible or do I have to implement something with the Machine Learning too?

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid... so what you want to do is detected an image and then if it gets recognised display some text on the screen about that picture?

Comment: @JoshRobbins Yes, right. excuse me if I explained myself badly

Comment: Having an app that can recognize artwork sounds like good idea indeed it would make life easier for museums to provide information (in several languages) without the need for printing anything in the nearby of the artwork. Just think about sculptures in an open area? The "problem" here is on how image recognition works and the chances to face serious copyright issues, image quality, file size of the ML model due to each image learnt is in fact an individual work, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine Learning requires lots of samples to be able to recognize images (with some space for errors), since paintings are unique ML doesn’t look like a valuable tool. I would use barcodes instead

visualize the text in AR would be quite easy

Comment: it should be easier to manage. In practice I have 3 images of predefined pictures that, once the frame is framed, recognizes it and then visualizes the text that I set. but I can not find any first guide on how to start, I'm new in swift and I do not even find any interested project already compiled on GitHub .. can you tell me something?

Comment: I’m sorry can’t suggest any good thing, image recognition works like we humans, we learn by experience an in the case of paintings we learn not by comparison but introspection and memorizing the actual artwork. Thanks for your vote :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure this [ARKit rectangle detection](https://github.com/mludowise/ARKitRectangleDetection) To replace the current sheet with an image + text and configure worldTracking to vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: I tried as you said and look for something else on GitHub but I did not find anything that was right for me. this you proposed me you do not work very well, framing a plan but does not recognize the surface well .. I would need something better, that inserting my images, if frame around recognizes them and makes me see the words ..